# Mock Entity framework 6 navigation properties using moq (or similar)

Tags: entity-framework, moq, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

This article: [Testing with a mocking framework (EF6 onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx) describes how to mock parts of entity framework.

I've not found many examples of this, does anyone have any examples of mocking a navigation property?

I'm using specflow, xunit and moq if it helps set the context for the question.

Comment: Navigation property is just regular property on your entity which returns either object instance or collection of object instances. What exactly is the problem with mocking that property? It has no direct relation to EF.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mock the property when it's a part of a mocked DbSet, I've tried a few options, but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track as I've seen no examples of such a thing.

Comment: The property is not part of mocked set. It is part of your entity. Mocking / Faking is not about simulating any logic but about verifying that something was called (mocking) or about providing test data (faking). Can you update your question with the test code demonstrating your issue?

Comment: True, that's what's puzzling me. If I mock the property, how do I inform context.DbSet.First().Navigation - so a route through the dbset that it should be using my mocked navigation properties? I'm using specflow to pass in two tables, and then trying to mock the relationships between the entites. So that if a navigation property is used I've got it mocked. It's a bit of an experiment at the moment with EF 6, as I realise repositories is an option.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, what is the answer to this?

Comment: Hi @MridusmitaDeka it's been a few years since I worked with Entity Framework properly, but my other question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645645/moq-testing-linq-where-queries/22784670#22784670

Also I understand with Entity Framework Core things have changed considerably, so you may wish to consider using the in-memory stub perhaps.