# Moq - mocking LINQ When & FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following code and I am trying to mock it, but my unit test fails.

Code:

```
await _someDataRepository.GetSomeDataAsync(false)
                         .Where(r => r.Code == statusCode)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Mock:

```
Mock<SomeDataRepository> _someDataRepositoryMock = new Mock<SomeDataRepository>();

_someDataRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetSomeDataAsync(It.IsAny<bool>()))
                       .Returns<List<Domain.Student.Entities.SectionRegistrationStatusItem>>(
                           i => Task.FromResult(
                               i.Where(sr => sr.Code == It.IsAny<string>())
                           )
                       );
```

How would I mock chained statements?

Comment: Note you can pass a predicate to `FirstOrDefault`, so `.Where(r => r.Code == statusCode).FirstOrDefault()` can just be `.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Code == statusCode)`

Comment: You can't mock `Where`/`FirstOrDefault` using Moq since they're [extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645645/moq-testing-linq-where-queries).

Comment: personally, I will not mock a linq query, instead, I will just mock the business logic, which is the method that contains the linq query; or mock the data access layer and make that return a certain set of data, so your real linq query will still execute, just against the mocked data

Comment: If `GetSomeDateAsync` returns `List<Domain.Student.Entities.SectionRegistrationStatusItem>` then how is it asynchronous?  Shouldn't it be returning a `Task`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioend in the comments, you can't mock `Where` and/or `FirstOrDefault`. You'd mock `_someDataRepository.GetSomeDataAsync(false)` and let `Where` work on the data that've return from `GetSomeDataAsync`.

Unfortunately I haven't tested this code, but it might give you some inspiration:

```
_someDataRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetSomeDataAsync(It.IsAny<bool>()))
                       .Returns(Task.FromResult(Your data here, i.e. List<Domain.Student.Entities.SectionRegistrationStatusItem>));
```

Or if you are using Moq 4.2 or later

```
_someDataRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetSomeDataAsync(It.IsAny<bool>()))
                       .ReturnAsync(Your data here, i.e.  List<Domain.Student.Entities.SectionRegistrationStatusItem>);
```